# Using private tokens in a public app

Tags: python, twitter

Well, I'm developing an app that calls the twitter API to get some information. So I registered as a twitter developer and I generated my four keys (consumer, consumer secret, access token and access token secret) but as you may have thought, the secret keys (and maybe the others too) have to be kept in secret. I, however, planned to put my source code into github and maybe sharing it with other people.

My question is: How can I publish my app while keeping those details secret?

I thought something about getting hashes and comparing them to some file with my hashes, but the idea doesn't completely clears up in my head. I'm using python to develop the app, if someone finds that relevant.

Comment: Keep your credentials in a configuration file, and don't make that part of your repository.  Anybody else who wants to run your code would need to generate their own credentials.

Comment: Why do you need to commit them to Github at all? Keep them secret, follow good [12-factor](https://12factor.net/) practice and get the values from the environment in production.

Comment: Create a 'config' file with all config data you need in your application (key, secret...) but with default value. Commit and push that to your repository. Change the value, update your .gitignore to ignore your config file. This way if someone use your project, he will have the infos but with fake data.

Comment: Do I have to encrypt my credentials or plain text is fine? (even though plain text sound awful)